# How to extract all property paths in JSON file having specific value

Tags: json, json.net

How can I collect all property paths in a large JSON file containing a specific case-sensitive value?

Here's an example:

JSON:

```
{
    "level1": {
        "level1node1": "hit",
        "level1node2": "miss",
        "level1node3": {
            "level2node1" : {
                "level3node1": "hit",
                "level3node2": {
                    "level4node1": "miss",
                    "level4node2": "hit"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Search text (case-sensitive): `"hit"`

Return C# string array:

```
[ "level1.level1node1",
  "level1.level1node3.level2node1.level3node1",
  "level1.level1node3.level2node1.level3node2.level4node2" ]
```

I'd like to use JSON.NET to get an array of matching node paths.

Comment: post your JSON and elaborate what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick:

```
        void AddPath(List<string> propertyPaths, JToken jToken, string searchForValue) {
        if (jToken is JValue && ((JValue)jToken).Value != null && ((JValue)jToken).Value.ToString() == searchForValue) {
            propertyPaths.Add(jToken.Path);
        } else if (jToken is JProperty) {
            ((JProperty)jToken).Values().ToList().ForEach(_ => AddMatch(propertyPaths, _, searchForValue));
        } else if (jToken is JObject || jToken is JArray) {
            if (jToken.HasValues) {
                jToken.Children().ToList().ForEach(_ => AddMatch(propertyPaths, _, searchForValue));
            }
        }
    }
```